# How to automatically close popup windows by using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I want to clear or automatically close popup windows through vbscript, but they may be different popup windows or may be a popup window within popup window.
I am using a vbscript to create pop a window and I want a script which will automatically close all the popup windows. Below is the script which creates pop up windows and I want to close all these pop up windows through script.

```
Dim WshShell, BtnCode
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
BtnCode = WshShell.Popup("Do you like your job?", 7, "Answer This Question:", 4 + 32)
Select Case BtnCode
case 6 WScript.Echo "That's great!."
case 7 WScript.Echo "Sorry to hear that."
case -1 WScript.Echo "No Response?"
End Select
```

My solution to above code where it works partially:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

Do 
    ret = wshShell.AppActivate("Answer this question") 
    If ret = True Then 
        wshShell.SendKeys "%Y" 
        Exit Do
     End If 
    WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop
```

Comment: Try [GUI for WSH VBS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47111556/2165759) instead of popups.

Comment: well thanks for your reply but i want to clear that the above code is an example created by me to show pop up windows but what i am trying to do is that i want to clear or close pop up windows. In simple words i want to close popup windows automatically through vbscript if a pop generates in my application like warning or some error type popups which comes up and i want to clear those popup windows

Comment: VBScript is not a best tool for that, take a look at AutoIt.

Comment: i know but i have to do it using vbscript..sorry but cant use autoit so i have to do using vbscript.Can ou help me with that

Comment: You could have a second script running which detects the popup and uses `SendKeys` to interact with the popup

Comment: @Dave can't i use all in single one script and can you help me in finding the solution for it for the above problem which i have mentioned..i mean if you can help me in the script part it would be helpful..

Comment: Not with the `Wscript.Echo` statements - the `Popup` method you used in the initial messagebox has a timeout parameter that will dismiss the message box after your specified delay.  Maybe use that?

Comment: @Dave that just a sample script to clear pop windows ut my main objective is to clear those windows through another script like in my application sometime some error or warnng popups comes so i have clear those popups.Below is the script which i tried ubt half work it oes it clears it but the last window it does not clear it so can you help me out with it.Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

Do 
    ret = wshShell.AppActivate("Answer this question") 
    If ret = True Then 
        wshShell.SendKeys "%Y" 
        Exit Do
     End If 
    WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to automate an application - if so, what tools are you using to do so?  Secondly, if you are going to post code, please edit it into your question rather than in a comment where it's pretty much impossible to read easily.

Comment: @Dave yes i am trying to automate an application..right now i am just using vbscript to automate it..one of my appplication while running shows popup windows sometimes while its running so i need to clear those popup winodws or error mesgaes which it comes as pop up..and for that i am using vbscript in order to clear the popup window...i have posted my code too where it partially works..